# c# copy console output to second location

Tags: c#, console

Using c#, is there anyway to copy console output to a second location (aswell as the original console). I know i can call SetOut to override the default output location of the console, but what i want to do, is keep writing to the original console implementation, but also write to a second location. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you look into [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Comment: Look at this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/420502/82447

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

```
FileStream ostrm;
StreamWriter writer;
TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;

try
{
    ostrm = new FileStream ("./Redirect.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    writer = new StreamWriter (ostrm);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
    Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
    return;
}
Console.SetOut (writer);
Console.WriteLine ("This is a line of text");
Console.SetOut (oldOut);
writer.Close();
ostrm.Close();
Console.WriteLine ("Done");
```