# why is TextWriter logging to file incomplete?

Tags: c#

I am attempting to follow [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19180846/8397835) to mirror my Console output to a log file as well, however, i noticed that the output to file gets cut off, so the full console output is not completely outputted in the file. Why is that? Is TextWriter limited to certain amount of lines?

```
private TextWriter txtMirror = new StreamWriter("mirror.txt");

// Write text
private void Log(string strText)
{
    Console.WriteLine(strText);
    txtMirror.WriteLine(strText);
}
```

p.s. the reason im using this solution is because I have `Console.Writeline` in functions as well that i call in the main(). so if i was to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6927051/8397835) instead, i would have to open a using statement everywhere i have a `Console.WriteLine()`...which seems redundant

Comment: Could you explain little bit more about the issue? `cut off` means the text contents are not completely written to the file? Did you consider using logging framework such as log4net, NLog etc for writing logs to text files?

Comment: Do you Flush / Close / Dispose your TextWriter?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya like for example if i have 100 statements/lines printed to the console, when i check the log file i see only about 60 statements/lines. i did consider log4net but for now im working on a simple console POC, so i'd rather not include 3rd party libraries/packages yet :)

Comment: @KlausGütter youre right, i have to add these 2 lines after every `Log("...") txtMirror.Flush();             txtMirror.Close();`. but `using` seems to take care of this in much more elgant way :)

Comment: You can add it also as last line in your Log method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AutoFlush` property [System_IO_StreamWriter_Flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.flush?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamWriter_Flush)

> Flushing the stream will not flush its underlying encoder unless you explicitly call Flush or Close. Setting AutoFlush to true means that data will be flushed from the buffer to the stream after each write operation, but the encoder state will not be flushed.

By the way, if you are instantiating your logger class many times, you are going to have many `StreamWriter` objects. Make sure you dispose them as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush?view=net-5.0)

> This type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly. To dispose of the type directly, call its Dispose method in a try/catch block. To dispose of it indirectly, use a language construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic). For more information, see the "Using an Object that Implements IDisposable" section in the IDisposable interface topic.

Disposing the objects, makes sure that `flush` is called and any buffered information is written to the underlying object.

Example:

```
// Write text
private void Log(string strText)
{
    Console.WriteLine(strText);
    using (StreamWriter txtMirror = new StreamWriter("mirror.txt")) {
        txtMirror.WriteLine(strText);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh so i have to add these 2 lines after every Log("...")? `txtMirror.Flush();
            txtMirror.Close();`

Comment: If you wrap the `StreamWriter`  with a using statement, when the code exits the using block, it will call `Dispose`/`close` and `flush`, without you needing to do anything.

Comment: I added the code with using. It should not miss any lines if you use it that way.

Comment: oh but now im losing the append capability, so it overwrites everything and leaves just the last line

Comment: what would be the equivalent of `FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write` for StreamWriter? im trying something like this: `using (StreamWriter txtMirror = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))` but this says `Cannot convert system.IO.FileMode to system.text.encoding`

Comment: oh nvm its just `true`! now its appending :) `using (StreamWriter txtMirror = new StreamWriter("mirror.txt", true))`

Comment: You can also use `File.AppendText(path)` to create a StreamWriter to append to a file!